# how to prove a task is done in minimum required commands

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to show that a task is done in the minimum amount of required commands or lines of code in a language, it is obvious that if you can do a task in one command this is the shortest way to do so but this is only going to be true of tasks like addition, if I say created an algorithm for sorting how would I know that there does or does not exist a faster way to carry out this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, minimum number of lines of code does not necessarily mean minimum number of commands. (i.e. processor commands) As the former is not really significant in an algorithmic sense, I am assuming that you are trying to find out the latter.

On that note, there are a variety of techniques to prove the minimum number of steps(not commands) needed to do some complex tasks. Finding the minimal number of steps necessary to achieve a task does not directly correspond to the minimum number of commands; but it should be relatively trivial to modify these techniques to find out the minimum number of commands essential to solve the problem. Note that these techniques may not necessarily yield a lower bound for every complex task, and whether a lower bound can be found depends on the specific task.

Incidentally, (*comparison-based*) sorting, which was mentioned in your question, is one of the tasks for which there is such a proof method, namely decision trees. You may find a more detailed description of the method on many sources including [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf) but the method simply tries to find the least number of comparisons that has to be made in order to sort an array. It is a well-known technique lying at the heart of proving why comparison-based sorting algorithms have a time complexity lower bound of `NlogN`.